# Component creation fails in jasmine test

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, ngrx

Given the following component that subscribes to an observable, (which runs fine in the app), it fails when trying to create the component through jasmine/karma.

> Uncaught Error: Error in ./MappingComponent class MappingComponent -
>   inline template:0:5 caused by: Cannot read property 'mapCursorClass'
>   of undefined
>       at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:84141:33)

Its something to do with he observable. If that is simply a string there is no bother:

```
    /**
     * Container component that composes the mapping toolbar (pan, zoom, drag, draw, measure etc)
     * and the mapping provider (underlying 3rd party mapping display engine - Leaflet, OpenLayers etc)
    */
    @Component({
        selector: 'mapping-component',
        //templateUrl: './mapping.component.html',
        template: '<div [ngClass]="mapCursorClass | async"></div>',
        styleUrls: ['./mapping.component.css']
    })
    export class MappingComponent extends events.EventEmitter {
        mapContainerElementId = "map-container";
        private mapCursorClass : Observable<string>;

        constructor(
            MappingProviders.MappingProvider,
            public mappingProvider: LeafletMappingProvider,
            private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
            private mapLayerService: MapLayerService,
            private organisationService: OrganisationService,
            private projectService: ProjectService
        ) {
            super();


            this.mapCursorClass = this.store.select(fromRoot.getMapCursor); // bound to the html
        }
```

and the spec:

```
describe('MappingComponent',
    () => {
        let component: MappingComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<MappingComponent>;

        // Add the imported module to the imports array in beforeEach 
        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [
                        AppModule,
                        StoreModule.provideStore({})
                    ]//,
                    //declarations: [MappingComponent]
                })
                .compileComponents();

        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MappingComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        it('should create',
            () => {
                expect(component).toBeTruthy();
            });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you have your component declaration commented out in your TestBed?

Comment: @Jason Lutz the AppModule pulls it in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the issue

```
StoreModule.provideStore({})
```

as it expects an `@ngrx/store reducer`, AppModule actually does that:

```
import { reducer } from './app.reducer';
...
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        /**
         * StoreModule.provideStore is imported once in the root module, accepting a reducer
         * function or object map of reducer functions. If passed an object of
         * reducers, combineReducers will be run creating your application
         * meta-reducer. This returns all providers for an @ngrx/store
         * based application.
        */
        StoreModule.provideStore(reducer),
```

Deleting that line from the fixture was the fix (alternatively i could reintroduce the component, fix that line with the right reducer and remove the AppModule import):

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                StoreModule.provideStore(reducer)
            ],
            declarations: [MappingComponent]
        })
        .compileComponents();

    }));
```

Comment: Generally you should try to take the second route so you aren't importing your entire app module in your unit tests. I had skipped over that you were importing it initially. The great thing about taking this approach is that you can mock out all the services you don't care about and focus on testing just your component.